# Show that the set of sets {$A_n$} has $n$ elements and that it is transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion

We define by recursion the set of sets {$A_n : n∈ℕ$} this way:

$A_0 = ∅$
$A_{n+1} = A_n ∪$ {$A_n$}.

I want to prove by induction that for all $n∈ℕ$, the set $A_n$ has $n$ elements and that $A_n$ is transitive (i.e. if $x∈y ∈ A_n$, then  $x∈A_n$).

My thoughts:

for $n=0$, $A_1$ = $∅ ∪$ {$∅$} = {$∅$}

then, for $n+1$: $A_{n+2}$ $= A_{n+1} ∪$ {$A_{n+1}$}

I'm confused on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that for induction problems, you must show (in addition to the base case) that if a claim holds for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then it also holds for $n+1$. In this problem, our claim is:
$$
\forall x : x \in y \in A_n \implies x \in A_n
$$
The base case ($n = 0$) is not difficult: Since there are no elements in $A_n$, there are no elements for which this is false! Therefore, it is true.

Next, we will assume that this claim holds for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider some $x$ such that $x \in y \in A_{n+1} = A_n \cup \{A_n\}$. By the definition of the union, we see that either $y \in A_n$ or $y = A_n$.

If $x \in y = A_n$, then, by definition of $A_{n+1}$ ($z \in A_n \text{ or } z \in \{A_n\} \implies z \in A_{n+1}$), we see that $x \in A_{n+1}$.

Otherwise, $x \in y \in A_n$. But this is true by our assumption!

Therefore, by induction the claim holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Edit: I missed the section regarding $| A_n | = n$

To show that $A_n$ has $n$ elements, use induction again. First, we need to show that:
$$\forall n : A_n = \{ A_i : i < n \}$$

For $n=0$, we see that this is trivially true, since there are no natural numbers less than $0$. Let us assume this claim holds for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then:
$$A_{n+1} = A_n \cup \{A_n\} = \{ A_i : i < n \} \cup \{A_n\} = \{ A_i : i \le n \} = \{ A_i : i < n+1 \}$$

Now that we know the above fact, we can show $| A_n | = n$.
For $n= 0$, $A_0 = \emptyset$ clearly has no elements. Next, assume that $A_n$ has $n$ elements for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $A_{n+1} = A_n \cup \{A_n\} = \{ A_i : i < n \} \cup \{A_n\}$. Since $A_n$ contains sets with at most $n-1$ elements, and since $A_n$ contains $n$ elements, we see that $A_n$ and $\{A_n\}$ are necessarily disjoint. Therefore, $| A_{n+1} | = n + 1$ ($n$ elements from $A_n$ and one element from $\{A_n\}$).

Comment: And how can I prove that $A_n$ has $n$ elements?

Comment: Shouldn't the inductive hypothesis be $A_{n+2} = A_{n+1} ∪$ {$A_{n+1}$}?

Comment: It's simpler to assume the claim for some $n$, then prove that it holds for $n+1$. Otherwise, your inductive step doesn't even include the $0$ case (As there is no natural number $k$ such that $k+ 1 = 0$), which no longer is induction.
You could add a ''$n = -1$'' case, but it would be much simpler to stick with an '$n \implies n+1$' approach.